# $\int_{0}^{r} \sqrt{\frac{1}{r^2-x^2}} \ dx$ with improper integration or trigonometric substitution?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I've always done this limit with improper integration because the denominator goes to zero, but is a trigonometric substitution valid as well? (edit, I know of the trigonometric substitution $x=r \sin\left(\theta\right)$ but because I'd have the limits of integration going from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ then wouldn't I still have an improper integral?)

For example, my denominator would be $\sqrt{r^2-r^2\sin\left(\theta\right)}$ and that would become $r\cos\left(\theta\right)$ but that would still be division by zero

Comment: Substituting $x=r\sin \theta$ works wonderfully.

Comment: thanks Tavish, but wouldn't I run into the problem of having $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{r \cos \theta}{r \cos \theta} d\theta $ being improper still, due to the limit of integraiton

Comment: Technically yes, but the integrand can be simplified to $1$ everywhere except at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, where you have to take a limit.

Answer (score 1):

It is a basic formula that the antiderivative is
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} \,\mathrm dx=\arcsin\frac xr +C,$$
so just apply the 2nd fundamental theorem of integral calculus.

Comment: But when it's a definite integral, wouldn't the limits matter? For example, although $\int \frac{1}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{x} + C$ wouldn't we need improper integral if it's $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: In this  case, sure.  But $\arcsin\dfrac xr$ is defined at the bounds, and continuous, so there's indeed an improper integral, but it goes without saying that the process will work.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know I could look at the bounds of arcsin and see that it could work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is $$I=\int_{0}^{r} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}$$
Note that $J=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{(x-a)^p} dx$ is finite if $p<1$.
It is in this sense that your integral $I$ is finite as $p=1/2$ here. Now take $x=r \sin t$, then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} 1 dt=\pi/2.$$